# hidden input id attribute with a specific value returns as undefined in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

Recently, using javascript(jQuery to be specific) I was working on a script that retrieves the value attribute from a hidden input field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="cost" value="" />
```

The input had an id of **cost**.

For some odd reason, in **ie7**, when I would output the value, it would always return **undefined**.

```
alert($("input#cost").attr("value")); // returns undefined...
```

After much frustration, I oddly enough changed the **id** of that input element to **price** which seems to have resolved the issue?

At this point everything is working again, but I am wondering if anyone can shed some light on what  might cause this type of behavior?

Comment: This sounds to me like there were multiple elements with `id="const"` in your page. If not, could you create a short but complete example demonstrating this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At this point everything is working again, but I am wondering if anyone can shed some light on what might cause this type of behavior?

That kind of error is usually caused by having multiple elements with the same `id`. According to the specification, `id` attributes need to be unique within the page.

Should you need to tag multiple elements with a single identifier, you should use a class.

Comment: Embarassingly, it was precisely that! Thank you for the comments, well appreciated.